# Route a PDF file to a clean url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, url-routing

I have a PDF located in /assets/images. I can view the PDF on this url:

```
/assets/brochure.pdf
```

I want the url to be:

```
/brochure
```

Here's what I'm trying, which isn't working.

```
get '/brochure' => 'images#brochure', as: :brochure
```

Answer (score 0):

you can symlink

```
public/assets/bochure.pdf
```

to

```
public/brochure
```

Comment: Do I need something in routes.rb?

Comment: nope. nothing. Anything in `public/` folder is picked up and served directly by the webserver and never hits `rails`. Though I recommend using the file extension for the symlink `public/brochure.pdf` since it helps browsers automatically figure out the mime-type.

Comment: I can't figure it out mate. What's a symlink? I put the file in public/assets. Is that all I need to do?

Comment: Did you try googling for "symlink"? If you do not know what it means.. I am sorry to say. You should stop working on rails for a few days and read up linux for dummies. SO is really not the place for tutoring.